# How to accept touch events in Qt6?

Tags: android, c++, qt

I tried to accept touch events in Qt6 like this, in main.cpp:

```cpp
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::ApplicationAttribute::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```

`error: no member named 'WA_AcceptTouchEvents' in 'Qt::ApplicationAttribute'`

IntelliSense shows that `Qt::ApplicationAttribute` has `WA_AcceptTouchEvents`. But I think it is a bug of Qt Creator because there is no `WA_AcceptTouchEvents` in `Qt::ApplicationAttribute`:

[image]

and I tried to run this code:

```cpp
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
```

`error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Qt::ApplicationAttribute' with an rvalue of type 'Qt::WidgetAttribute'`

I tried to accept it in the window constructor but `QOpenGLWindow` doesn't have the `setAttribute` method:

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'setAttribute'; did you mean 'QInputMethodEvent::Attribute'?`

```cpp
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
{
    setTitle("OpenGL ES 2.0, Qt6, C++");
    resize(350, 350);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
}
```

My pro-file:

```
QT += core gui opengl widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
# DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    opengl_window.cpp

HEADERS += \
    opengl_window.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**Added**

**musicamante** posted the next link and the quote in the comments below:

> the documentation ([Event Handling](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtouchevent.html#event-handling)), "Unlike widgets, QWindows receive touch events always, there is no need to opt in. When working directly with a QWindow, it is enough to reimplement QWindow::touchEvent()"

But when I run the next code on the real device, touch a screen (it prints `counter = 0`), holding a finger on the screen, try to touch with another finger and doesn't print the next line like `counter = 1`. It seams like multi touch is disabled.

```cpp
void OpenGLWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
            qDebug() << "counter = " << m_counter;
            m_counter++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Cross-ref: https://forum.qt.io/topic/155009/how-to-accept-touch-events-in-qt6

Comment: Please include the code as code, not images.

Comment: The compiler is right - there is no WA_AcceptTouchEvents in Qt::ApplicationAttribute, only ion [Qt::WidgetAttribute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

Comment: [QT docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) say that you need to `QWidget::setAttribute()`, so what is `OpenGLWindow`?

Comment: You seem to be trying things randomly. As it should be clear from the documentation, `WA_*` enums are part of **widget attributes**, which, for obvious reasons cannot be arbitrarily used for anything that is not a widget like QApplication or QWindow objects. Also, again from the documentation ([Event Handling](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtouchevent.html#event-handling)), "Unlike widgets, QWindows receive touch events always, there is no need to opt in. When working directly with a QWindow, it is enough to reimplement QWindow::touchEvent()".

Comment: @chehrlic IntelliSense shows that `Qt::ApplicationAttribute` has `WA_AcceptTouchEvents`. I posted a screenshot. I think it is a bug of Qt Creator

Comment: @pptaszni I deleted images. I thought that it will be more clear.

Comment: @musicamante But when I run a code with `touchEvent` (see a code in my post) on the real device, touch a screen (it prints `counter = 0`), holding a finger on the screen, try to touch with another finger, and doesn't print the next line like `counter = 1`. It seams like multi touch is disabled.

Comment: @8Observer8: since QtCreator has no IntelliSense I don't know what you are trying to tell me. There is no need fora full qualification of the enum value here since it's a plain enum and not an enum class.

Comment: @8Observer8 QTouchEvent groups multiple touch points, adding a finger doesn't create a new `TouchBegin`, but a `TouchUpdate` event, you need to accept the begin event in order to receive update events, similarly to what happens with `MouseButtonPress` and `MouseMove` events. It's all explained in the same section I linked above, have you actually read it all?

Comment: @chehrlic Yes, sorry. Qt Creator doesn't have IntelliSense because "IntelliSense is a Microsoft autocompletion technology best known in Microsoft Visual Studio. Adds the name of the function when entering initial letters." I don't know what the autocompletion technology in Qt Creator is called. I just wanted to point out that the completion system in Qt Creator assumes that WA_AcceptTouchEvents is in the Qt::ApplicationAttribute.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you very much! I added a solution to the end of the topic.

Comment: Just for a note for the future. If I use `QOpenGLWidget` instead of `QOpenGLWindow` I should to call in the constructor: `setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);` This is wrong to call the next command inside of main.cpp: `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);`

Comment: I wrote a solution for my problem here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/155009/how-to-print-coordinates-of-fingers-in-qt6-for-qopenglwindow

Comment: @8Observer8 Please don't put answers in the question body, that's not how the website works. I've voted your question for reopening, as soon as it will be you'll be able to post your solution as an *actual* answer by using the related button. Also, avoid adding cross-post links (you've already done it in the past): unless the other link provides further insights that *actually* expand/explain what you're already writing here, there's no reason for anybody to go through a full thread that will possibly contain the same information you already providing.

Comment: @8Observer8 That "wrong call" is obviously wrong for the reasons explained above: you can set widget attributes on widgets, not on the application. There should be no need to remark it, as it should be quite clear by reading the related documentation of either QWidget.setAttribute() or QCoreApplication.setAttribute(). As said, you need to pay more attention to the documentation, and be more patient in your learning/solving.

Comment: @musicamante why if I call `print(dir(Qt.ApplicationAttribute))` in PyQt6 I don't see `WA_AcceptTouchEvents`? Qt Creator should not show `WA_AcceptTouchEvents` if I type `Qt::ApplicationAttribute::`

Comment: @musicamante I create the topic: "Qt Creator assumes that WA_AcceptTouchEvents is in the Qt::ApplicationAttribute" https://forum.qt.io/topic/155020/qt-creator-assumes-that-wa_accepttouchevents-is-in-the-qt-applicationattribute

Comment: @8Observer8 Autocompletion is just an interpreted (and not always reliable) extension of the semantics, not the proper logic syntax: what matters is the actual implementation done at compile/run time. `print(dir(Qt.ApplicationAttribute))` will obviously show `AA_*` (**A**pplication**A**ttribute) enums, not `WA_*` ones: completion is based on automated parsing and follows independent logic that may be inconsistent with the interpreter/compiler. It can be a Creator bug, but it's quite irrelevant: python (and C++) access the actual objects, and `ApplicationAttribute` only contains `AA_*` enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **musicamante** wrote in the comments the answer is in the documentation:

> from the documentation ([Event Handling](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtouchevent.html#event-handling)), "Unlike widgets, QWindows receive touch events always, there is no need to opt in. When working directly with a QWindow, it is enough to reimplement QWindow::touchEvent()".

A very useful note about multi touching from **musicamante**:

> `QTouchEvent` groups multiple touch points, adding a finger doesn't create a new `TouchBegin`, but a `TouchUpdate` event, you need to accept the begin event in order to receive update events, similarly to what happens with `MouseButtonPress` and `MouseMove` events.

I should pay more attention to documentation.

This code example works for me:

opengl_window.h

```cpp
#ifndef OPENGL_WINDOW_H
#define OPENGL_WINDOW_H

#include <QtGui/QTouchEvent>
#include <QtOpenGL/QOpenGLWindow>

class OpenGLWindow : public QOpenGLWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OpenGLWindow();

private:
    void touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event) override;
    int m_counter = 0;
};

#endif // OPENGL_WINDOW_H
```

opengl_window.cpp

```cpp
#include "opengl_window.h"

OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
{
    setTitle("OpenGL ES 2.0, Qt6, C++");
    resize(350, 350);
}

void OpenGLWindow::touchEvent(QTouchEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
            qDebug() << "touch begin";
            event->accept();
            break;
        case QEvent::TouchEnd:
            qDebug() << "touch end";
            break;
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
            qDebug() << "counter = " << m_counter;
            m_counter++;
            for (int i = 0; i < event->points().length(); i++) {
                int x = event->points()[i].position().x();
                int y = event->points()[i].position().y();
                qDebug() << x << " " << y;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "opengl_window.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::ApplicationAttribute::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    OpenGLWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

pro

```
QT += core gui opengl widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    opengl_window.cpp

HEADERS += \
    opengl_window.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```